# Issues using Selenium in EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run a Selenium web scraper in an EC2 istance. I'm pretty new to this so I followed the guide here https://medium.com/@praneeth.jm/running-chromedriver-and-selenium-in-python-on-an-aws-ec2-instance-2fb4ad633bb5
And got chromedriver and google chrome installed. However when I try to run a script that attempts to open chromedriver I get an error, "unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally."
There isn't a lot of good information and I have no idea what is causing this.

This is the exact error I am getting.
https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*RLSHpS4ZLmnhRcvduEhWXA.png

This test code will show the error if it doesn't work.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

print('trying to open webdriver now')
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.stackoverflow.com/")
```

Comment: Post your scrip

Comment: there I editted the original post with some sample code.